# How to insert data in a particular row in listview item in c#?

Tags: c#, listview

I have a `listView`. I want to add data in row number one, column number two. I have tried the following:

```
listView1.Items[0].Subitems[1].Text = "my data";
```

I get an error like this '0' is not a valid index. Then i tried this:

```
if (listViewDownloadList.SelectedItems.Count == -1)
        {
            listViewDownloadList.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text = "Hello";
        }
```

Now, nothing is happening. No insert, no error.

But it doesn't work. Can you help me out here?

Comment: Does your list view having item at index 1 which you want to update or you want to insert new row?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the code. I already have a row. There are six column in the row. Everyone of  them has a value without column 2 that is `items[0].Subitems[1]`. I want to add data in that position. how can i do that?

Comment: Can you please explain did your list view have column index 1 to which you want to update?

Comment: yes, there are six column in the row. Everyone of then has data. I want to update the mentioned position.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error  '0' is not a valid index  because your list view did not have any element.
First you need to create a row like below-

```
 string[] row = { "Hello" };
 var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
```

Then you need to add that row into listview like below-

```
listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
```

Comment: I already have a row. There are six column in the row. Every column has data without column 2. I want to add data in the column two. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this work `listView1.Items[0].Subitems[1].Add("my data")`?

Comment: No, doesn't work. Says listViewItem.SubItem doesn't contain a definition for `add`

Answer (score 0):

You can add only `subitem` to **existing** item in `listView` like this:

```
listView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 20);
listView1.Width = 250;

// The View property must be set to Details for the 
// subitems to be visible.
listView1.View = View.Details;

// Each SubItem object requires a column, so add three columns.
this.listView1.Columns.Add("Key", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
this.listView1.Columns.Add("Co1 1", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
this.listView1.Columns.Add("Col 2", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);


// Add a ListItem (row1) object to the ListView.
ListViewItem row1 = new ListViewItem();
row1.Text = "Row 1";
row1.SubItems.Add("A");
row1.SubItems.Add("");
listView1.Items.Add(row1);


// Add a ListItem (row2) object to the ListView.
ListViewItem row2 = new ListViewItem();
row2.Text = "Row 2";
row2.SubItems.Add("");
row2.SubItems.Add("B");

listView1.Items.Add(row2);


// Add a SubItem to existing item (row1)
System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem item1 = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
item1.Text = "C";

listView1.Items[0].SubItems[2] = item1;
```

**Result**

[image: listView]

Comment: @Rubel Hosen Has my solution worked well? Solved your problem?